# Single Vendor different custom Modules

Tags: magento2

Can we use  2 different modules(say CatalogSearch and LayeredNavigation) in a single custom overridden vendor.

ie) I have

**Vendor/MyCatalogSearch** and

**Vendor/MyLayeredNavigation**

both the modules under single "**Vendor**"

Or should i use as below?

**Vendor1/MyCatalogSearch**

**Vendor2/MyLayeredNavigation**

Comment: Is this the Magento2 standard of using under 2 different Vendors or can it be used as the 1st way as shown!

Comment: You can use single vendor for multiple modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single vendor (naming convention) for multiple modules.

For example

> Mycommonvendor/Moduleone
>
> Mycommonvendor/Moduletwo

**One**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mycommonvendor/Moduleone',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Two**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mycommonvendor/Moduletwo',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Note : Not recommended to use core modules naming convention.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually my doubt was... Say for eg i am overriding Result.php from CatalogSearch module... Now i want to override this class in 2 different custom modules...Should i override the same class in 2 different modules?

Comment: Which custom modules 'type' in di will it consider?

Comment: If Module "A" is overriding result.php. You need to override module 'A' by other module 
(Module "B") to override result.php again.

Comment: Can u check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131556/calling-same-overridden-custom-class-from-2-modules   have described what i asked

Comment: Assume the question intention is Naming convention. Still have doubts please ask new question with what you have tried.