# Calling same overridden custom class from 2 modules

Tags: magento2

I have a custom overriden class say **Result.php** overridden from CatalogSearch module.

Now if i have to use this Result class in 2 different modules(Module1 and Module2), do i have to override the class in both the modules (in the 'type' attribute of di)??

**etc/di of Module1:**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor/Module1/Block/Result">
```

**etc/di of Module2:**

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor/Module2/Block/Result">
```

In the above case, if i want to track as to which Result from my custom module is getting called?

**PROBLEM:**

I tried echo in Module1's Result class somefun(), i get it, but i comment out the same and try in Module2's Result class somefun(), i dont get

Why?

Can i use something like this in **Module2** di.

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor/Module1/Block/Result">
```

I gave module1 in type

Comment: So @Krishna, as per your explanation should my module2's di be like this?  <preference for="Vendor/Module2/Block/Result" type="Vendor/Module1/Block/Result">

Comment: But all my functions in both the classes are same

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

UPDATED

```
<preference for="Vendor\Module2\​Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module1‌\Block\Result">
```

Do not use all functions unless you need to modify, if function is not found it will look into parent class.

I have added a small example to have the basic fallback.

1. **First module (Vendor\Module)**

\app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Result" />
</config>
```

Create Block

\app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Result.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Result extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result
{
        protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo "Vendor\Module";
        exit;

        //return parent::_prepareLayout();

    }
}
```

2. **Second module (Vendor\Moduletwo)**

\app\code\Vendor\Moduletwo\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Vendor\Module\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Moduletwo\Block\Result" />
</config>
```

Create Block

\app\code\Vendor\Moduletwo\Block\Result.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Moduletwo\Block;
class Result extends \Vendor\Module\Block\Result
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        echo "Vendor\Moduletwo";
        exit;

        //return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Run setup-upgrade, remove cache and search some string in header mini search.

Please consider this is an example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result comes under preference or type?

Comment: in line1 while overriding 1st module, preference for should be  Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result rite?  @Krishna

Comment: i use the above @Krishna, still my 1st module class is getting called!

Comment: Ill try and update @Krishna